# How to configure mobile as DHCP server?

Tags: ip, dhcp-server

I want to use my mobile (with internet GPRS/EG) as server. I mean, I hace my PC (not in network) and my mobile (with internet). I want to connect my pc to mobile and use.

So, when I connect my PC to mobile, who will assign ip address to pc? Is mobile having DHCP server? if not, what is the alternative?

Comment: Without some idea what handset you are using (and, if it is a smartphone, what OS it is using) there is no way for anyone to suggest anything that might help beyond Danish or RedGrittyBricks answers below.  Bluetooth tethering can generally achieve what you are after, but if you only have wifi or usb access to the phone then software specific to you phone platform is required.

Comment: With my Android phone (6.0 aka Marshmallow), if I use tethering through USB or Bluetooth my PC sees an Ethernet-type connection with an address in the 192.168.X.Y range (typical of small local networks). So I assume the Android app that setups uo the tethering does the DHCP server as well.

Answer (score 2):

The term is [Tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering), and each device has its own way to do it. It also depends on your Mobile Service provider to allow tethering and use it with your computer.

If you can update your question with handset information, may be you would get some specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a [Mifi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiFi) device such as [this](http://www.three.co.uk/Mobile_Broadband/MiFi) or [this](http://www.novatelwireless.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Using tethering your smartphone will  behaves like access point. Then you connect your computer to this access point in the same way you do with wireless router.
 Note: when you enable tethering in your smart phone, this later link your computer to the network ( 3G,4G, gprs.......) so you get access to these service

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mobile phones have a DHCP server. Otherwise tethering or mobile hotspot would not work.